# Do I need to handle nulls on LEFT JOINs?

Tags: sql-server, null, left-join

There is a more senior SQL developer (the DBA) at the office who told me that in all the LEFT JOINS of my script,  I must handle the scenario where the join column of the left table is possibly null, otherwise, I have to use INNER JOINs. Now, being a noob, I might be wrong here, but I can't see his point and left me needlessly confused.

His explanation was, unless the column is non-nullable, either I must

1. use `ISNULL(LeftTable.ColumnA,<replacement value here>)` on the ON clause, or
2. handle null values in the ON clause or the
   WHERE clause, either by adding  `AND LeftTable.ColumnA IS NOT NULL` or `AND LeftTable.ColumnA IS NULL`.

I thought those are unnecessary, since one uses a LEFT JOIN if one does not mind returning null rows from the right table, if the values of the right table join column does not match the left table join column, whether it be using equality or inequality. My intent is that it does not have to be equal to the right table join column values. If the left table join column is null, it is ok for me to return null rows on the right table, as a null is not equal to anything.

What is it that I am not seeing here?

MAJOR EDIT:

So I am adding  table definitions and scripts. These are not the exact scripts, just to illustrate the problem. I have remove earlier edits which are incorrect as was not in front of the script before.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Contact (
    ContactID int NOT NULL, --PK
    FirstName varchar(10) NULL, 
    LastName varchar(10) NULL,
    StatusID int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Contact_ContactID 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContactID)   
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.UserGroup (
    UserGroupID int NOT NULL, --PK
    UserGroup varchar(50) NULL,    
    StatusID int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_UserGroup_UserGroupID
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserGroupID)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.UserGroupContact (
    UserGroupID int NOT NULL, --PK,FK
    ContactID int NOT NULL,  --PK,FK
    StatusID int NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_UserGroupContact_UserGroupContactID 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserGroupID, ContactID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserGroupContact_UserGroupId
        FOREIGN KEY (UserGroupId) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[UserGroup](UserGroupId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserGroupContact_ContactId 
        FOREIGN KEY (ContactId) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Contact](ContactId)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Account (
    AccountID int NOT NULL,  --PK
    AccountName varchar(50) NULL,   
    AccountManagerID int NULL, --FK     
    Balance int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Account_AccountID 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AccountID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Account_AccountManagerID 
        FOREIGN KEY (AccountManagerID) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Contact](ContactId),
);
GO
```

My original query would look like below. When I say "left table", I mean the table on the left of the ON clause in a join. If "right table", its the table on the right of the ON clause.

```
SELECT 
    a.AccountId,
    a.AccountName,
    a.Balance,              
    ug.UserGroup,
    ugc.UserGroupID,                
    a.AccountManagerID,
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName
FROM  dbo.Account a             
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact c 
        ON a.AccountManagerID = c.ContactID     
        AND c.StatusID=1                                    
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UserGroupContact ugc 
        ON a.AccountManagerID = ugc.ContactID   
            AND ugc.StatusID=1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UserGroup ug 
        ON ugc.UserGroupID  = ug.UserGroupID    
            AND ug.StatusID=1                           
WHERE 
    a.Balance > 0   
    AND ugc.UserGroupID = 10   
    AND a.AccountManagerID NOT IN (20,30)
```

Notice in the example script above, the first and second left joins has a nullable column on the left table and non-nullable column on the right table. The third left join has both  nullable columns on the left and right tables.

The suggestion was to "change to inner join or handle NULL condition in where clause" or "There is use of LEFT JOIN but there are non null conditions referenced in the WHERE clause."

The suggestion is to do either of these depending on intent:

a) convert to inner join (not possible as I want unmatched rows from Account table)

```
SELECT 
    a.AccountId,
    a.AccountName,
    a.Balance,              
    ug.UserGroup,
    ugc.UserGroupID,                
    a.AccountManagerID,
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName
FROM  dbo.Account a             
    INNER JOIN dbo.Contact c 
        ON a.AccountManagerID = c.ContactID     
        AND c.StatusID=1                                    
    INNER JOIN dbo.UserGroupContact ugc 
        ON a.AccountManagerID = ugc.ContactID   
            AND ugc.StatusID=1
    INNER JOIN dbo.UserGroup ug 
        ON ugc.UserGroupID  = ug.UserGroupID
            AND ug.StatusID=1                           
WHERE 
    a.Balance > 0   
    AND ugc.UserGroupID = 10   
    AND a.AccountManagerID NOT IN (20,30)
```

b) handle nulls in WHERE clause (not possible as I want to return rows with nulls on column a.AccountManagerID and on ugc.UserGroupID)

```
SELECT 
    a.AccountId,
    a.AccountName,
    a.Balance,              
    ug.UserGroup,
    ugc.UserGroupID,                
    a.AccountManagerID,
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName
FROM  dbo.Account a             
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact c 
        ON a.AccountManagerID = c.ContactID     
        AND c.StatusID=1                                    
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UserGroupContact ugc 
        ON a.AccountManagerID = ugc.ContactID   
            AND ugc.StatusID=1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UserGroup ug 
        ON ugc.UserGroupID  = ug.UserGroupID
            AND ug.StatusID=1                           
WHERE 
    a.Balance > 0   
    AND ugc.UserGroupID = 10   
    AND a.AccountManagerID NOT IN (20,30)
    AND a.AccountManagerID IS NOT NULL
    AND ugc.UserGroupID IS NOT NULL
```

c) handle nulls in ON clause (I settled on this which I thought doesn't make sense because it's redundant)

```
SELECT 
    a.AccountId,
    a.AccountName,
    a.Balance,              
    ug.UserGroup,
    ugc.UserGroupID,                
    a.AccountManagerID,
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName
FROM  dbo.Account a             
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact c 
        ON a.AccountManagerID = c.ContactID     
        AND c.StatusID=1                                    
        AND a.AccountManagerID IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UserGroupContact ugc 
        ON a.AccountManagerID = ugc.ContactID   
            AND ugc.StatusID=1
            AND a.AccountManagerID IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UserGroup ug 
        ON ugc.UserGroupID  = ug.UserGroupID
            AND ug.StatusID=1               
            AND ugc.UserGroupID IS NOT NULL         
WHERE 
    a.Balance > 0   
    AND ugc.UserGroupID = 10   
    AND a.AccountManagerID NOT IN (20,30)
```

I did not provide example for ISNULL(). Also, I think he was not referring to implicit inner joins.

To recap, how do I handle this suggestion: "There is use of LEFT JOIN but there are non null conditions referenced in the WHERE clause."? He commented it's a "questionable LEFT JOIN logic".

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. The idea of a `LEFT JOIN` is that the object on the "Right" side will return a row, even is nothing is returned in the left. Values of columns in the left table will have the value *`NULL`* where no rows were returned. If, however, you then reference that column in your `WHERE` then you would turn your `LEFT JOIN` into an implicit `INNER JOIN`; perhaps that is what your senior is on about? `LEFT JOIN YourTable YT ON YT..ID = OT.ForeignID OR YT.ID IS NULL` is pointless; Especially as ID is likely a `PRIMARY KEY`, and thus cannot have a value of *`NULL*`.

Comment: I believe your DBA is right when you are joining by more than 1 column.  However, finding a good example with a multiple column join that some might be null isn't easy.

Comment: I think your confusion reflects on the clarity of your question. I've read it twice already and didn't understand what you are asking. Perhaps you should ask your DBA for clarification.

Comment: So, wait, the problem is that the value `NULL` could be in the right table, not the left? Is that correct? If the right table has a value of *`NULL`*, what value are you looking to `JOIN` on in the left?

Comment: @Larnu: No, actually, he wants me to handle nulls on either columns. The column on the right could be nullable, but of course, not all rows are nulls, some have values. I am ok with nullable columns on the right. However, I could not understand the need to handle nullable column on the left, because I thought that is implicit in the left join syntax. A null on the left column will just return null rows on the right, so that is ok with me. But he wants me to "handle" that, which confuses me.

Comment: OK, but that's doesn't answer my question, what row are you expecting to `JOIN` on if the right table has a value of *`NULL`*? Using `OR E1.ID IS NULL` would mean that **every** row in the left table would be returned is `E1.ID` has a value of *`NULL`*; that can't be intended behaviour.

Comment: @Larnu: Now this is getting confusing. Ok, this is how I understand it. For me the left table is E1, which is on the left of "=" and E2 is the right table, which is on the right  of  "=". The right table, E2, column SomeOtherValue is not entirely null values, it's nullable, some are null values, some are non-null values.  What i expect  to happen is that the right table will only return rows that matches the left table. Nulls on the right table will not be returned. Nulls on the left table will not return any rows on the right as well. I'm not sure if that is how you understand it too.

Comment: I also see the "right" table as the one the data would be returned from. So in the example `SELECT * FROM E1 LEFT JOIN E2 ON...` E1 would be the "right" table.

Comment: @Larnu: LOL! for me that is the left table. Therefore, the answer to your question is "nothing".  Using your terms, the "left table" will have null rows, which is what I expect.

Comment: Hi. Please use enough words, phrases & sentences to be clear. You are unclear. *What should the output be when nulls are input?* "handle" is unexplained & the references to queries & circumstances by you & your DBA are vague. Please make a [mcve] with two tables with 2 or 3 columns & rows and one left join; show example input, desired output & actual output; explain how the desired output is a function of the input clearly enough that someone could code the query without examples. Give DBA quotes that *clearly* refer to input values & query parts to say how they are wrong & why.

Comment: @Larnu & Noble_Bright_Life It's *left table* LEFT JOIN *right table* ON *condition*. Which returns INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by by nulls.

Answer (score 1):

One thing your question doesn't talk about is ANSI NULLs, whether they're on or off.  If ANSI NULLs are on, comparing NULL = NULL return false, but if they're off, NULL = NULL returns true.

You can read more about ANSI NULLs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql

So if ANSI NULLs are OFF, you very much care about matching a NULL foreign key to missing row in a join.  Your rows with NULL foreign keys are going to match every single row where the left table was all NULLs.

If ANSI NULLs are ON, the LEFT OUTER JOIN will behave as expected, and NULL foreign keys will not match up with NULL primary keys of other missing rows.

If another dev is telling you that you need to be careful about NULLs in OUTER JOINs, that's probably a good indication that the database you're working with has ANSI NULLs OFF.

Comment: Thanks. It is on. I run `select sessionproperty('ANSI_NULLS')` and its 1.

Answer (score 1):

> one uses a LEFT JOIN if one does not mind returning null rows from the right table

*Left table* LEFT JOIN *right table* ON *condition* returns INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by by nulls.

One uses left join if that's what one wants.

> the join column of the left table

A join is not on "the join column"--whatever that means. It is on *the condition*.

That *might*, say, be one column in the left table being equal to the same-named column in the right. Or be a function of one column in the left table being equal to the same-named column in the right. Or be a boolean function of same-named columns. Or involve/include any of those. *Or be any boolean function of any of the input columns.*

> If the left table join column is null, it is ok for me to return null rows on the right table, as a null is not equal to anything.

It seems you are suffering from a fundamental misconception. The only thing that is "ok for me to return" is *the rows you were told to return, for certain possible input*.

It's not a matter of, say, coding some condition on some tables because we want certain inner join rows and then accepting whatever null-extended rows we get. If we use a left join, it's because it returns the correct inner join rows & the correct null-extended rows; otherwise we want *a different expression*.

It is not a matter of, say, a left table row having null meaning that that row must not be part of the inner join & must be null-extended. We have some input; we want some output. If we want the inner join of two tables on some condition *no matter how that condition uses nulls or any other input values* plus the unmatched left table rows then we left join those tables on that condition; otherwise we want *a different expression*.

(Your question uses but doesn't explain "handle". You don't tell us *the rows you were told to return, for certain possible input*. You don't even give us example desired output for example input or your actual output for some query. So we have no way of adddressing what your DBA's critique is trying to say about what you ought to do or what you are doing your queries.)

Answer (score 0):

Going to expand a bit on my comment here; this, however, is guess work based on what we have at the moment.

based on your current wording, what you've stated is wrong. Let's take these simple tables:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Example1 (ID int NOT NULL, SomeValue varchar(10));
GO
CREATE TABLE Example2 (ID int NOT NULL, ParentID int NOT NULL, SomeOtherValue varchar(10));
GO

INSERT INTO Example1
VALUES (1,'abc'),(2,'def'),(3,'bcd'),(4,'zxy');
GO
INSERT INTO Example2
VALUES (1,1,'sadfh'),(2,1,'asdgfkhji'),(3,3,'sdfhdfsbh');
```

Now, let's have a simple query with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Example1 E1
     LEFT JOIN Example2 E2 ON E1.ID = E2.ParentID
ORDER BY E1.ID, E2.ID;
```

Note that 5 rows are returned. No handling of *`NULL`* was required. if you added an `OR` to the `ON` it would be non-sensical, as `ParentID` cannot have a value of *`NULL`*.

If, however, we add something to the `WHERE` for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Example1 E1
     LEFT JOIN Example2 E2 ON E1.ID = E2.ParentID
WHERE LEFT(E2.SomeOtherValue,1) = 's'
ORDER BY E1.ID, E2.ID;
```

This now turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an implicit `INNER JOIN`. The above would therefore be better written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM Example1 E1
     JOIN Example2 E2 ON E1.ID = E2.ParentID
WHERE LEFT(E2.SomeOtherValue,1) = 's'
ORDER BY E1.ID, E2.ID;
```

This, however, may not be the intended output; you may well want unmatched rows (and why you intially used a `LEFT JOIN`. There are 2 ways you could do that. The first is add the criteria to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Example1 E1
     LEFT JOIN Example2 E2 ON E1.ID = E2.ParentID
                          AND LEFT(E2.SomeOtherValue,1) = 's'
ORDER BY E1.ID, E2.ID;
```

The other would be do add an `OR` (don't use `ISNULL`, it affects SARGability!):

```
SELECT *
FROM Example1 E1
     LEFT JOIN Example2 E2 ON E1.ID = E2.ParentID
WHERE LEFT(E2.SomeOtherValue,1) = 's'
   OR E2.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY E1.ID, E2.ID;
```

This, I imagine is what your senior is talking about.

To repeat though:

```
SELECT *
FROM Example1 E1
     LEFT JOIN Example2 E2 ON E1.ID = E2.ParentID OR E2.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY E1.ID, E2.ID;
```

Makes no sense. `E2.ID` cannot have a value of *`NULL`*, so the clause makes no change to the query, apart from probably making it run slower.

*Cleanup:*

```
DROP TABLE Example1;
DROP TABLE Example2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples and quick reply, but my understanding is that he is not referring to those three examples with left joins. I will update the question with a query using your example.

Comment: You actually have 5 left join examples, and I also think that the last doesn't make sense. I could not understand if you think your 4th example is acceptable or not.

Comment: @Noble_Bright_Life There are 5 queries with a `LEFT JOIN`, yes, however, only 4 of them are actually a `LEFT JOIN` (One is an implicit `INNER JOIN`). The 4th is perfectly acceptable. I stated that using `ISNULL` is bad, not `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

in my eyes this is very simple, as far as I understood it.

Let's try with an example.
Imagine to have 2 tables, a master and a details table.

MASTER TABLE "TheMaster"

```
ID  NAME
1   Foo1
2   Foo2
3   Foo3
4   Foo4
5   Foo5
6   Foo6
```

DETAILS TABLE "TheDetails"

```
ID  ID_FK   TheDetailValue
1   1   3
2   1   5
3   3   3
4   5   2
5   5   9
6   3   6
7   1   4
```

TheDetails table is linked to TheMaster table through the field ID_FK.
Now, imagine to run a query where you need to sum the values of the column TheDetailValue. I would go with something like this:

```
SELECT TheMaster.ID, TheMaster.NAME, Sum(TheDetails.TheDetailValue) AS SumOfTheDetailValue
FROM TheMaster INNER JOIN TheDetails ON TheMaster.ID = TheDetails.ID_FK
GROUP BY TheMaster.ID, TheMaster.NAME;
```

You would get a list like this:

```
ID  NAME    SumOfTheDetailValue
1   Foo1    12
3   Foo3    9
5   Foo5    11
```

But, what is your query uses a LEFT JOIN instead of a INNER JOIN? For example:

```
SELECT TheMaster.ID, TheMaster.NAME, Sum(TheDetails.TheDetailValue) AS SumOfTheDetailValue
FROM TheMaster LEFT JOIN TheDetails ON TheMaster.ID = TheDetails.ID_FK
GROUP BY TheMaster.ID, TheMaster.NAME;
```

The result would be:

```
ID  NAME    SumOfTheDetailValue
1   Foo1    12
2   Foo2    
3   Foo3    9
4   Foo4    
5   Foo5    11
6   Foo6
```

You will obtain a NULL for each master field having no values in the details table.
How do you exclude these values? Using an ISNULL!

```
SELECT TheMaster.ID, TheMaster.NAME, Sum(TheDetails.TheDetailValue) AS SumOfTheDetailValue
FROM TheMaster LEFT JOIN TheDetails ON TheMaster.ID = TheDetails.ID_FK
WHERE (((TheDetails.ID_FK) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY TheMaster.ID, TheMaster.NAME;
```

...which would take us to these results:

```
ID  NAME    SumOfTheDetailValue
1   Foo1    12
3   Foo3    9
5   Foo5    11
```

...which is exactly what we obtained before using an INNER JOIN.

So, in the end, I guess your collegue is talking about the use of the ISNULL function, in order to exclude the records having no relation in another table.

That's it.

For example purpose only the query were made using MS Access (rapid test), so the ISNULL function is implemented with "Is Null", which can become "Is Not Null". In your case probably it's something like ISNULL() and/or NOT ISNULL()

Comment: But I am not actually wanting to exclude those rows in the Master table with no values in the Details table.

Comment: The asker is concerned re when there are nulls in the *input*. They seem to think something (wrong) like that a left table row with a null *must* have its null extension in the output. But they aren't clear. See my answer.